# How to get a forum container with contextual filter in a block?

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

I am using [advanced forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module, [organic group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) and [organic forum d7](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_forum_d7) module. I have created several groups, that all will have the same pages (group-blog, group-documents, group-members, group-wiki etc.). These pages are created as group content and do have the path-pattern:`[node:og_group_ref]/[node:title]`
For these pages I am creating views as block with all the needed content types (blogs, wiki, material etc) and I am setting a contextual filter to group id, and provide default value from og context.

Now, I also would like to add a group forum container. I manage to create a forum container for this group, but I can't get it as a block on such a page like the other content with the current contextual filter from the organic group.

Any ideas how to manage this?